# Great quality Mobizen recordings?

Tags: video-recording

I recently started using Mobizen for my Android and the quality of the real time recording from the phone to my computer screen is very low quality.

Does anyone know how to improve the quality without significantly increase the delay time during USB connection?

If there are no methods to getting a better quality recording is there an alternative to Mobizen which does NOT require rooting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about improving the quality on Mobizen as I don't use it but an alternative would be to use ADB's `screenrecord`. But seeing as (as far as I am aware) Mobizen uses this anyway, the recording quality would probably not be much better. You could try a different USB cable or changing the bitrate while using `adb screenrecord`.